# Is there any way make QImage support ARGB1555

Tags: qt, argb

I need read the raw data(bgra5551) into QImage and display it and write the QImage to raw data back(bgra5551), Qt only supports Format_RGB555, is there any way make `Format_RGB555` transparent(alpha channel 255)?

I tired this:

```
QImage getImage(uchar* data, int width, int height){
    return QImage(data, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB555).copy();
}
uchar* getData(QImage img){
    return img.bits();
}

QImage imgRGB555 = getImage(bgra5551, width, height);
// problem1: imgRGB555 is not transparent.
uchar* org = getData(imgRGB555);
// problem2: bgra5551 != org
```

Comment: You could provide an example of the file, zipped, upload it to drive, dropbox or similar and share the link.

Comment: read this: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq17-imageio.html